# Issue on stretching the groupbox in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, stackpanel, groupbox

I have an design as below.

```
<Dock:ContentPane x:Name="grouping" Header="{lex:LocText Res:Titles:CustomFields}"  
                    Visibility="{Binding ShowGroups, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityCollapseIfFalse}, Source={x:Static Management:UserPreferencesManager.Instance}}" >
    <ScrollViewer Style="{DynamicResource VerticalScrollViewerStyle}" >
        <DockPanel Style="{DynamicResource DefaultPanelStyle}" >
            <SKUL:CustomFields />
            <SKUL:CustomFieldsPortrait Windows:OrientationMonitor.HorizontalVisibility="Collapsed" />
        </DockPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Dock:ContentPane>
```

My CustomeFields.xaml

```
<Expander IsExpanded="{Binding ExpanderSetting}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>                    
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <GroupBox Style="{DynamicResource DefaultGroupBoxStyle}" Header="{lex:LocText Res:Titles:ItembyLocationGroups}" >
            <Common:CustomFields DataContext="{Binding Grouping.SKULGroups}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Expander>
```

When i strech my stackpane,my groupbox is not getting streched.How can i achieve it.I tried using HorizontalAligment="strech" verticalAligment="strech" properties,but it didnt work

Comment: Do you have a Height/Width defined in the DefaultGroupBoxStyle ?

Comment: No.Height & width is not defined for DefaultGroupBoxStyle

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem found when developers use a `StackPanel`. This `Panel` does *not* perform resizing actions like some other `Panel`s in WPF. To rectify the problem, simply replace the `StackPanel` with a `Grid` or other `Panel` that *does* provide children resizing capabilities.

You can find out more about the different `Panel`s and their different resizing strategies from the [Panels Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

---

UPDATE >>>

> *In My RowDefinition Height in given 145,is that causing issue?*

I imagine so... any `Height`s or `Width`s that you set on the `GroupBox` or any of its parent controls will stop it from stretching to the full `Height` or `Width` of the application. Take a look at this example that demonstrates the differences between the `StackPanel` and the `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="Red">
        <GroupBox Background="LightGreen">
            <GroupBox.Header>Some Header</GroupBox.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Some Content" FontSize="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </GroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Background="LightGreen">
        <GroupBox.Header>Some Header</GroupBox.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Some Content" FontSize="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: In My RowDefinition Height in given 145,is that causing issue?

Comment: I tried your above sample.Scrollbar is not showing up,when i destrech it

Comment: What `Scrollbar`? I haven't used any in my example. If you added that code into a `ScrollViewer`, then of course it won't display a `ScrollBar`... you'll have to set a `Height` or `Width` constraint before the `ScrollViewer` could know when to display the `ScrollBar`.